# Using Snowflake in .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How I can use Snowflake in .NET Framework v4.5?

I try to include and got errors

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3274: The primary reference "Snowflake.Data" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"

Answer (score 1):

They have never compiled their code with 4.5. You could try 4.6 if you can update your project - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Snowflake.Data/1.2.3